# Regex behaves different for mobile [on iOS] and desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I know it sounds strange, but for some reason my regex works very good for desktop, but when it comes to mobile it doesn't recognize the pattern on iOS only.

The idea is the capture the following patterns:

- Name 0:02
- Name 0:02:00
- [ Name: 0:03 ]
- [ Name: 0:03:00 ]

Here's my regex:

```
/(^\s*)?(\[?)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\.\d*)?(\]?\s*)/
```

This is how I use it

```
const App = () => {
  const text = "Welcome 0:00"
  const result = text.match(
    /(^\s*)?(\[?)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\.\d*)?(\]?\s*)/,
  );
  return(
    <div className="box">
      <h1>{result}</h1>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can even see the results in the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/or-nakash/pen/WNJbKKK

If you use desktop you'll see the result, but if you enter this link from mobile you will see it's empty (because it's null).

Do you have any idea what could have caused this?

Comment: The regexp is unreadable, but apart from that I don't see anything that would hit browser compatibility. What browser are you using on your desktop vs your mobile?

Comment: @Halcyon I am using chrome browser for both, but it happens in Safari as well

Comment: @OrNakash I guess it's something about iOS compatibility because my android phone match the same behavior as desktop do.

Comment: @Jaood_xD thanks for the comment, yes I am using iOS but I thought it happens to android as well - I'll update the question!

Comment: Any browser for iOS is actually the same browser, since Apple doesn't allow different engines in its OS. So I suppose the problem is related to safari for iOS

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Thanks, that's what I thought. So I am actually running Safari on chrome, right?

Comment: It's good to separate browers and rendering engines. Chrome uses Blink, Safari uses Webkit. But on iOS Chrome also uses Webkit because Apple says they have to. See why talking about browser compatibility is so complicated? :P What makes it more complicated is that you can't test Webkit on non iOS devices, so blame Apple for that.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciated help and information, @Halcyon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that [`match` returns an array of all groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value), and you pass the full array to the template - that's why the result is incorrect and the hour is printed twice:

```
const text = "Welcome 0:00"
const result = text.match(
    /(^\s*)?(\[?)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\.\d*)?(\]?\s*)/,
);
// result is ["0:00", undefined, "", "0:00", undefined, undefined, ""]
```

You want to use the first element in the array (`{result[0]}`), which is the full match (or a specific group, but this pattern doesn't have a group for the hour only). The rest of the elements are the captured groups (every `(...)` will add an element).

You can try capturing the hour only, this can simplify the pattern:

```
/\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(?:\d{1,2})?(?:\.\d+)?/
```

I used non-capturing groups `(?:...)` because that's better when we don't need to extract and use the captured value.
The optional groups for spaces and brackets in the original pattern don't add much anyway (for example, it doesn't try to capture "Name").

As for the `null` - this looks like a bug in Safari! Safari doesn't like it what you have an optional `^` - my guess is that this is an optimization gone wrong:

```js
console.log("a 1".match(/(^)?\d/));
```

Comment: oh, and sorry just in case  `<h1>{result}</h1>` was done on purpose to debug and you already know all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh you know what, It's probably that trailing comma:

```
  const result = text.match(
    /(^\s*)?(\[?)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\.\d*)?(\]?\s*)/,
//  ----------------------------------------------------------^
  );
```

Some browsers don't like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! unfortunately that didn't help (you can check the codepen link I provided and see in mobile it doesn't work)

Comment: I just found out it happens only on iOS, if that helps

Comment: I don't have any iOS devices so I can't help you.

Comment: This _should be_ ok, (but yeah, sometimes iOS is weird): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#trailing_commas_in_functions